# What a blitzed through means

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In 2014, Islamic State blitzed through half the country and threatened the capital

Answer (score 1):

Blitz, noun and verb, comes from the German blitzkrieg:

noun

1. an intensive or sudden military attack.
2. INFORMAL a sudden, energetic, and concerted effort, typically on a specific task.

"a major press blitz”

verb

1. attack or damage (a place or building) in a blitz.
   "news came that Rotterdam had been blitzed"
2. AMERICAN FOOTBALL
   attack (the passer) in a blitz.

From Oxford via Lexico.com